# core data not saving in .sql lite file

Tags: ios, core-data

I am implementing core data into an existing project.

When the application runs frst time then the sqllite db gets created but when I try to insert data by calling [managedObjectContext save:] then nothing happens. I don't even getting the error.

I have checked the timestamp of the sqllite file. it is not getting updated. 
Please help.

Comment: provide some details. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I very often have similar problem and the reason is I forget the .sql file is already created,  and it doesn't overwrite, if I change the .sql structure I uninstall and install again in the simulator or device and then it works fine.

Comment: i have seen the sqllite file. the empty table structure. only rows are not being inserted.

Comment: in viewcontroller i am writting following way to insert:self.managedObjectContext = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];FeedEntry *model = (FeedEntry *)[NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FeedEntry"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [model setValue:((RSSEntry *)[firstArray objectAtIndex:0]).blogTitle forKey:@"blogTitle"];if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming your sqlite db is created in the /documents folder.**

```
CoraDataEntity *entity = (CoraDataEntity *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CoraDataEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSError *error = nil;

if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){

    NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unresolved error saving core data context: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]];
    NSLog(@"%@",msg);

}
```

Comment: exactly i am doing that only. here is my code.in viewcontroller i am writting following way to insert:self.managedObjectContext = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];FeedEntry *model = (FeedEntry *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FeedEntry" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; [model setValue:((RSSEntry *)[firstArray objectAtIndex:0]).blogTitle forKey:@"blogTitle"];if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) { NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]); }

Comment: i have seen the sqllite file. the empty table structure. only rows are not being inserted.

Comment: How did you create your .sqlite file? How did you set up the persistentStoreCoorinator in the appdelegate?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the rollback files as well and then run the sqlite3 on the main file.
Instead of just using the .sqlite file, copy also the .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal.